# why does sizeof vector and array gives different output

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, sizeof

when I try to take the element by sizeof , then I am getting different answers in array and vector

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    vector<int> num = {1,2,5,4};
    int k = sizeof(num)/sizeof(num[0]);
    cout << k << endl;
    int nums[] = {1,2,5,4};
    int w = sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0]);
    cout << w << endl; 
}
```

Expected 4 4

Output 3 4

Comment: The size of the vector is not dependent on the number of elements.

Comment: why did you exect that output? Did you read about what `sizeof` does?

Comment: *Expected 4 4* -- It would help if you stated why you expected this output, so that others know where the fault you're making is.

Comment: The short answer is that `vector` is not an array. It's a reasonable first interpretation that `sizeof(x)/sizeof(x[0])` is how you obtain all container lengths, but it's not true.

Comment: well i am storing integer in both cases. how is that different size is allocated in two cases ??

Comment: ok, back to the second comment:  Do you know what `sizeof` does?  A vector *dynamically*, at runtime, creates entries.  The `sizeof` knows nothing about what happens at runtime, as it is a compile-time construct.

Comment: Max Langhof well i was hoping to get the array length by this method.

Comment: @iabhishek15 Unlike inbuilt arrays, most C++ containers store the actual data "somewhere else", which `sizeof` cannot know about. `sizeof(x)` is a constant known at compile-time, so it cannot possibly tell you how many elements a container like `vector` contains at runtime.

Comment: PaulMcKenzie it can be used to get the size of classes, structures, unions and any other user defined data type. well i get the point what you are trying to say .it actually gives only 12 bit of memory for vector.

Comment: @iabhishek15 -- Think of it this way -- the `sizeof` is like knowing how tall a building is.  It doesn't tell you how many people are in the building, as that can change.

Comment: @iabhishek15 _it can be used to get the size of classes,..._ That's exactly what you get. `sizeof(num)` is a byte-size of an object of type `std::vector<int>`. Vectors typically consist of 3 pointer member variables. On your architecture, pointers are seemingly 32-bit, therefore `sizeof(num)` is 12. Then, `sizeof(num[0])` is a byte-size of an object of type `int` which is 4. Finally, 12/4=3, which is a result you get.

Comment: Max Langhof , Daniel Langr , PaulMcKezie thnx now i understand .

Comment: `struct Holder { char* s; }; Holder holder; holder.s = new char[100]; auto sz = sizeof holder;` ... sz will be the number of bytes of a pointer (and maybe some padding bytes on some platforms).  Even though the pointer contained in holder refers to an array of 100 char.

Comment: Side note: Arrays are an elegant 1970s solution to vexing 1970 problems. While they are still very useful and form the basis for many other structures, the cracks start showing as soon as you start trying to pass arrays around and assign them. Case in point: the clumsy `sizeof(nums)/sizeof(nums[0])` used to get the number of elements vs the `size` method of a container class. Consider using [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) unless you really do need the simplicity and light weight of an array.

Answer (score 1):

Let's see what sizeof returns:

> [sizeof](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/sizeof) Queries size of the object or type.
>
> When applied to a class type, the result is the size of an object of
>   that class plus any additional padding required to place such object
>   in an array.

---

`vector<int>` and `int []` are totally different things.  Vector uses dynamic storage while array uses automatic storage.

`sizeof(vector)` return the size of vector class. It doesn't work the way you expect for the same reason it won't work on a dynamiclly allocated array.