# Is the actual location where the elements inside the std::vector<std::string> are stored in the heap or stack?

Tags: c++

As for `vector<char>` and `vector<int>`, the `char` elements and the `int` elements are both stored in the stack,but what about a `vector<string>`?

If I want to store a huge `vector<string>` with many strings, should I use `new vector<string>` to store my vector in the heap?

Comment: _"As for `vector<char>` and `vector<int>`, the `char` elements and the `int` elements are both stored in the stack"_: This is incorrect.  `std::vector` always dynamically allocates its elements.

Comment: So the sizeof(vector<A>) is always the same?@MilesBudnek

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  For any given type `T`, `sizeof(std::vector<T>)` is constant.  In fact that is the case for any type.  For any type `T`, `sizeof(T)` is constant.

Comment: @MilesBudnek `std::vector<bool>`: hold my beer

Comment: @bolov Even `std::vector<bool>` allocates its elements externally.  For all its oddities,  `sizeof(std::vector<bool>)` is still constant.

Comment: @MilesBudnek yes, of course. I was just making ... a joke. Because `sizeof(std::vector<T>)` is the same across all `T`s, except `bool`.

Comment: @keyzhao *"So the sizeof(vector<A>) is always the same?"* -- See [why does sizeof vector and array gives different output](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58399544) and its duplicates.

Answer (score 3):

You're over-thinking this.

Just use `vector<string>`. It manages the allocations for you, and `sizeof(std::vector<...>)` is fixed and reasonable.

Even then, if you were using `std::array` which acts a lot more like a C array, size and all, `std::string` will use dynamic allocation if necessary.

Using `new std::vector<...>` is hardly ever necessary.